# How can I send an email with the data posted on a class-based form in Django

Tags: python, django, email

I have a class-based view on my django app that grabs quote requests that are filled in the form and stores that information in the database.

I'd like to use send myself and email when somebody does that and include the data in the mail subject and message.

I got the e-mail part right and I can send a predefined message. but can't find a way to use the entered information.

Here's what I have so far:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),   
    path('quote/', QuoteCreateView.as_view(), name='quote'),
    path('quote/thankyou/', views.quoteThankyou, name='quote_thankyou'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class QuoteCreateView(CreateView):
    login_required = False
    model = Quote
    fields = ['fullname','email','date','description']

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user

        return super().form_valid(form)

def quoteThankyou(request):
    subject = 'Message subject'
    message = 'Message'
    send_mail(
        subject,
        message,
        'sender@email.com',
        ['receiver@email.com'],
        fail_silently=False,
        )
    return render(request,'blog/quote_thankyou.html')
```

**models.py**

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    date_sent = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname 

    def get_absolute_url(self): 
        return reverse('quote_thankyou', kwargs={})
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: In the class QuoteCreateView you can override the save() method and include the call to quoteThankyou in there. BTW, for function views the naming convention would be quote_thank_you, not in camel case.

Comment: Be careful sending emails within the view though. This will block the next view from loading until the email has sent. Any issues with this will cause the site to hang. You should generally send emails asynchronously using celery, or something similar. https://medium.com/@EmadMokhtar/send-emails-asynchronously-from-django-3c1e41b526c3

Answer (score 0):

You can define success_url, when you receive a valid form, redirect to the specified url.

It will look like this:

views.py

```
from django.urls import reverse

class QuoteCreateView(CreateView):
    login_required = False
    model = Quote
    fields = ['fullname','email','date','description']
    success_url = reverse('quote_thankyou')

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user

        return super().form_valid(form)

def quoteThankyou(request):
    subject = 'Message subject'
    message = 'Message'
    send_mail(
        subject,
        message,
        'sender@email.com',
        ['receiver@email.com'],
        fail_silently=False,
        )
    return render(request,'blog/quote_thankyou.html')
```

This redirect the user to the url "quote_thankyou" after submitting a valid form, and the view, will send the email.